# Style a bar graph in a Laravel app with labels for the x and y axes

Tags: laravel, charts

bars in graph does appear well apear with too much width in my small laravel project also labels both on y-axis and x-axis also can't bee seen as i wanted

the code base is trying to solve but can't style better as required

```
  <canvas class="my-4 w-100" id="myChart" width="900" height="380"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>


  <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: {!! json_encode($dailySales->keys()) !!},
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Daily Sales',
                data: {!! json_encode($dailySales->values()) !!},
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)', // Set bar color
                borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                borderWidth: 2,
            }]
        },
        options: {
    scales: {
        x: [{
            type: 'category',
            time: {
                unit: 'day',
                displayFormats: {
                    day: 'MMM D'
                }
            },
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Date'
            },
            ticks: {
                autoSkip: false, // To display all labels
            },
            labels: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'] // Add day names
        }],
        y: [{
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString:[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDsWB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDsWB.png) 'Total Sales'
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'top'
        }
    },
    layout: {
        padding: {
            left: 15,
            right: 20,
            top: 20,
            bottom: 20
        }
    },
    scales: {
        x: {
            barPercentage: 0.9, // Adjust bar width
            categoryPercentage: 0.9 // Adjust category width
        }
    }
       }

    });

  </script>
```

this query daily sales has to display x axis days of the week for each sale but also has to show date of the day in that particular day